# Missing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics assembly

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

I got the following exception when my WebRole tries to start:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

I use Visual Studio 2012 with Azure SDK 2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nuget didn't reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics and microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime

You have to reference it manually.

Answer (score 8):

Try find in your .csproj file the following:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0 />
```

and replace it with

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.1.0.0 />
```

Comment: unfortunately, nuget didn't reference this assembly.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that all versions of the Storage dll are the same version in the csproj xml. I had one that was 2.0 and one 2.1 and it causes that problem.